# No connection to tables, sprocs etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have been working on a database for a couple of weeks now, and suddenly nothing works and I just can't figure out how to solve it.

I can login to SQL server and list all the tables and sprocs. The problem is that when I try to run a sproc I get a message telling me that there are no such table, even though it exists.

When I try to alter or create a sproc I get the following message:

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Procedure usp_GetUser, Line 14
>   CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently running against the master database rather than whichever user database you have been working on.

Either run

```
use MyDatabaseName
```

Or at the top of SSMS there is a drop down that currently says ''master". Change it to your database name

Answer (score 4):

> ... in database 'master'.

Wrong database context: I assume it should be "MyDatabase" not "master"